# Enable/disable inputs based on dropdown selection (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, input, selection, state

I got two inputs and one dropdown per row in my website.
To explain it properly.

I got the input: "Start" and "End" to set opening times for my store and a dropdown to choose if the day is "completely closed" or "24 h open". And this for each day in the week.

Depending on the selection of the drop down, I want to disable the input fields. So if I choose "closed", the two fields "Start" and "End" shall be disabled, but JUST for the day and not for all days.

**My attempt**
I managed to disable and enabled all "Start"/"End" inputs based on the selection.

**JS:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dropdown = $('.dropdown_time'),
    $time = $('.timepicker');
    $dropdown.change(function() {
    if ($dropdown.val() != '1') {
        $time.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $time.attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
    }
    }).trigger('change'); // added trigger to calculate initial state
});
</script>
```

**HTML (stripped down to "two days":**

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="store_tuesday" class="right inline">Dienstag:</label>
    <input type="text" class="timepicker" placeholder="Von">
    <input type="text" class="timepicker" placeholder="Bis">
    <select name="store_opening_tuesday" id='customDropdown' class='medium dropdown_time'>
        <option value="1">Ruhetag</option>
        <option value="2">24 Std.</option>
        <option value="3" selected="selected">-</option>
    </select>   
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label for="store_wednesday" class="right inline">Mittwoch:</label>
    <input type="text" class="timepicker" placeholder="Von">
    <input type="text" class="timepicker" placeholder="Bis">
    <select name="store_opening_wednesday" id='customDropdown' class='medium dropdown_time'>
        <option value="1">Ruhetag</option>
        <option value="2">24 Std.</option>
        <option value="3" selected="selected">-</option>
    </select>   
</div>
```

**Goal:**
The dropdown per row shall just disable/enable the inputs in "his" row, not in the others. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure each row separately.  Using your code it would be like so:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.row').each(function(){
            var $dropdown = $(this).find('.dropdown_time'),
            $time = $(this).find('.timepicker');
            $dropdown.change(function() {
                if ($dropdown.val() != '1') {
                    $time.removeAttr('disabled');
                } else {
                    $time.attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
                }
            }).trigger('change'); // added trigger to calculate initial state
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If you're working with jQuery 1.6 and above, I'd recommend using `.prop('disabled', true)` to disable and element, and `.prop('disabled', false)` for the reverse.

Comment: This doesn't work properly. When I choose "Ruhetag" for, in example, Tuesday, it works. But when I choose "Ruhetag" (closed) for a second or third day, it disables all inputs again. Afterwards, when I choose "24 Std." on one of the disabled inputs, it enables the chosen row again. BUT when I enable a second one, it disables the previous inputs. Weird! :D